# Windows .exe is not running in Linux

Tags: window

i am a software developer. i had develop application using vs2010 and want to run in Linux .the problem is, .exe installed successfully in Linux but not running i had every thing from my side but nothing happen so please help me..

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to install is wine. Wine is a windows emulation software for linux. To install use following command:

sudo apt-get install wine

Then run your executable with command:

wine my_executable.exe

With winetricks script you can install any required libraries your program uses. In your case vc2010. To check the actual library follow the terminal output of the above command.

To install winetricks, simply download the winetricks script from its homepage and run with

./winetricks.sh

If you are a friend of GUI applications, you can try playonlinux. It already contains wine and it is also able to install required libraries to your wine virtual drive.